# Expected Waiting Time in a Poisson Process when Events have different Probabilities

Tags: poisson-process, queueing-theory

Assume I have service times distributed according to a poisson process. There are 3 servers with service rates $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ and each customer needs to visit them all in the same order. If I already have e.g. a customer $C_1$ at server 2  and customer $C_2$ at server 3 and a new customer $C_{new}$ enters the system, I want to know the expected time until he will be at server 3.

The intuitiv approach would be to add up the service times at the desks and also add the remainder of service time of a customer already at a desk, when the new customer arrives there. But that does not sound correct since the poisson process is memoryless.

**Can I combine expected waiting times here, weighted by their probability?** So when $C_{new}$ leaves server 1, I would now add $P(C_1\text{ already left})\frac{1}{\lambda_2} + P(C_1\text{ still at server 2})(2\frac{1}{\lambda_2})$ and similarly at server 3.

Comment: it seems on the right track, but you are assuming that C1 is at the server, therefore as you say for the memoryless property, you expect him to remain there for $\lambda_1$.  When 1 finishes, he may or may not be blocked by 2, and that may or may not have an effect on new.  Similarly as they move to server 3, they may block

Comment: @Cato yeah I screwed that up, it should have been that $C_1$ is at server 2 and $C_2$ at server 3. Edited it. But is the probabilistic approach true?

Comment: it would seem to be a valid approach, are you going to do it via integration?

Comment: By integration, I got that the expected wait to get into the second queue, after clearing queue 1 is  $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$

Comment: so you'd add a $1/\lambda_1$ and a $1/\lambda_2$ to that for expected time to clear 2 queues, if 2 is initially occupied

Comment: What do you mean with by integration? Can you explain the steps? @Cato

Comment: do you have an expression for P(C1 already left)?  If you have that, your suggested approach looks ok